# How to access datetime field outside of transaction with kotlin exposed

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I've got an exposed DAO-style setup with a `datetime`-column and want to access it after I received the row from the schema.

Table:

```kotlin
object Entries : IntIdTable() {
    val date = datetime(name = "date").nullable()
}
```

Entity:

```kotlin
class Entry(id: EntityID<Int>) : IntEntity(id) {
    companion object : EntityClass<Entry>(Entries)

    var date by Entries.date
}
```

DAO:

```kotlin
object DB {
    private val pool = BasicDataSource()
    private val database: Database

    init {
        pool.url = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/test"
        pool.driverClassName = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
        pool.username = "user"
        pool.password = "secret"

        pool.minIdle = 5
        pool.maxIdle = 10

        database = Database.connect(pool)
    }

    infix fun <T> query(block: DB.() -> T): T {
        return transaction {
            block.invoke(this@DB)
        }
    }
}
```

Main:

```kotlin
fun main() {
  val entry = DB.query {
    Entry.all().single() // There is only one row at this point
  }

  println(entry.date) //! Error is thrown on this line
}
```

It throws a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transaction in context.`. When I move the `println` into the transaction, it works as expected. If I change the type of the column to `varchar` and expect a `string` it works in both cases.

How can I get the date outside of the transaction? I think it worked a few versions back, but I'm unsure.

Comment: What Exposed version and database do you use?

Comment: @Tapac I use Exposed 0.17.14 and MySQL "Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.4.18-MariaDB, for Win64 (AMD64)" on my dev-machine.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by updating the Exposed dependencies to the latest version, which has a new naming pattern.

Old dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
  <artifactId>exposed</artifactId>
  <version>0.17.14</version>
</dependency>
```

New dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
  <artifactId>exposed-core</artifactId>
  <version>0.36.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
  <artifactId>exposed-dao</artifactId>
  <version>0.36.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
  <artifactId>exposed-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>0.36.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jetbrains.exposed</groupId>
  <artifactId>exposed-java-time</artifactId>
  <version>0.36.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Looks a little more bloated, but I guess it's cleaner to not have every possible module of Exposed loaded every time.

*Side note:*
I needed to update some imports (IntIdTable, EntityId, etc. and datetime are now located in new packages) and replace `Entries.date eq null` by `Entries.date.isNull()` in queries.